# How to multiply string that occur at different indices python

Tags: python, list

I am trying very hard to write a function that will duplicate the first string in a list into 6 places and duplicate the ones that occur at even indices into two places,if it occurs at an index that is a multiple of three, duplicate three times. However, if it occurs at both an even index and at an index that is a multiple of three, it should duplicate it into six places. Here is the code i have written but it seems not to be solving it dynamically as soon as i change input and target more cases i get this error :

```
IndexError: list index out of range


def multiply_strings(test):
    test[0] *= 6
    test[2] *= 2
    test[3] *= 3
    test[4] *= 2
    test[6] *= 6
    test[8] *= 8

    return test
test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
print(multiply_strings(test_list))
```

this prints

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is not the desired output.

am expecting it to print

```
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']
```

But am expected to take care of other cases like

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
```

this will print.

```
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG', 'H', 'II']
```

There are also other edge cases similar to this one i already posted.

Comment: how can that generate an error? which error? there are more than 7 items in both lists, it _has_ to work

Comment: Why are you trying to multiply test[8] by 8 instead of by 2?

Comment: And do you really need to modify the given list in-place *and* return it? That's rather unusual.

Comment: `test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]` can be simplified to `test_list = list("ABCDEFG")`

Answer (score 2):

Just some oneliners...

```
>>> a = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

>>> [(6, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1)[i % 6] * s for i, s in enumerate(a)]
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']

>>> [(1 if i % 2 else 2) * (1 if i % 3 else 3) * s for i, s in enumerate(a)]
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']

>>> [(bool(i % 2) or 2) * (bool(i % 3) or 3) * s for i, s in enumerate(a)]
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']
```

Rather annoying that the first one is the shortest. I like the others better. I found `(2 - i % 2)` for factor 2 but nothing that short for factor 3...

Edit: Another short one:

```
>>> [(min(i % 6, -i % 6) or 6) * s for i, s in enumerate(a)]
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to iterate over the index/value pairs of the list. Then just apply your logic to update the values in-place, e.g.:

```
def multiply_strings(strings):
    for i, s in enumerate(strings):
        k = 1
        if i % 2 == 0:
            k *= 2
        if i % 3 == 0:
            k *= 3
        strings[i] = s*k

strings =  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]    
multiply_strings(strings)
print(strings)  # ['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is very similar to the above poster, but with a test for length of the list in the beginning and slight difference in the looped conditional. Either work for what you're trying to do.

```
def multiply_strings(test):
    if len(test) > 0:
        test[0] *= 6
        for i in range(1, len(test)):
            k = 1
            if i % 2 == 0:
                k *= 2
            if i % 3 == 0:
                k *= 3
            test[i] *= k
    return test

>>>test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
>>>print(multiply_strings(test_list))
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG', 'H', 'II']
```